# Applet printing coordinates

Tags: tcl

I've been looking for a GUI where the user can load an image and, using the mouse, place points in the GUI. The coordinates of the points should then be exported to a file or standard output. As far as I recall, I've seen a small Tcl/Tk applet doing exactly this. Anyone on the net who knows anything about such an applet?

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming. If you are writing such a script and run into problems, feel free to ask questions about those problems.

Comment: Applets are strongly discouraged these days, but Tk's got the tools to make such an application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Tk library BLT (http://wiki.tcl.tk/199) might have some of the functionality you're looking for; you'd have to code the application yourself, however. This idea can easily be implemented with a simple `canvas` widget.

Try looking on the software recommendations stack exchange for this software: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
StackOverflow is specifically reserved for programming-oriented questions.